# How to create Light smear in blender animation

Tags: animation, light

[image]

In this picture, I'd like to make Light smears to express much more speeds in animation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is that you enable Motion Blur in your Render Properties:

[image]

With that enabled, and a camera animated and your "car" (my "cude"/cube in the following) Copy Location constraint Influence < 1.0, the rendering will show both blurred, light more blurred than the cube:

[image]

I leave your the [image] file here.

Answer (score 1):

The glow can be created by using a glare node in the compositor.  Since the second accomplishes most of what you want, here's an example:

I created a simple sphere and give it two materials, a shiny dark blue, and a white emission:

[image: dark blue sphere with emission]

dark blue shader:

[image: dark blue shader]

emission shader:

[image: emission shader]

This is all basic stuff, of course.  Next I rendered the image with F12 and then I went to the Compositing work space and created the glow:

[image: glow filter]

The result looks like this:

[image: fog glow]

You can control the strength and size of the fog flow of course.